# How do I remove the preinstalled Apache web server on Mac OS X Lion Server?

Tags: osx-lion, apache-http-server, uninstall, osx-server

I want to remove the preinstalled web server from my Mac OS X Lion Server.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that.  Please [ask about what you're actually trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56366/can-we-get-people-to-directly-ask-about-their-problems-instead-of-topics-they-th).

Comment: What do you mean? I don't need the preinstalled web server, it is old and not updateable, I wanna use macports to install a new one.

Comment: In that case, removing the preinstalled Apache is irrelevant at best, and dangerous at worst.  Just install the MacPorts version in /opt/local/bin (or wherever) and launch that instead of the preinstalled version.  The real questions have to do with how (/if) to integrate the MacPorts Apache with Lion Server's configuration interface and web-related services (Wiki, WebDAV, WebMail, Profile Manager, etc).  (And how to do that depends on what your goals are...)